# VB - Count how many times a string appears in .CSV file

Tags: string, vb.net, csv, count

New user and new coder here.

I am trying to find a way of counting how many times a particular string appears in a .CSV file that is located on the Desktop, and storing that number as a variable for further use.

An example of the .CSV would be:

REF,STATUS,NAME

99991,WordA,CustName1

99992,WordA,CustName2

99993,WordA,CustName3

99994,WordA,CustName4

99995,WordB,CustName5

99996,WordB,CustName6

99997,WordB,CustName7

I basically want to find out how many times WordA appears in the .CSV file, or how many rows in the sheet contain WordA. In my case this figure would be the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a list.

```
Dim l As New List(Of String)
l.Add(lines)
Dim i As Integer = l.FindAll(WordA).Count()
```

There are probably 100 ways to do this. It would be more helpful if you attempted a method of doing it and then asked questions on the specific method.